# Kohana login

Tags: kohana

Не работает авторизация. Создание пользователя:

```
public function action_create()
{
    $auth = Auth::instance();
    $user = ORM::factory('user');
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password  = $auth->hash_password($_POST['password']);
    $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];

    $user->email = $email;
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->username = $nickname;
    $user->birth = $month." ".$day." ".$year;

    $user->save();

    $user = ORM::factory('user');

    $role = ORM::factory('roles');
    $role->user_id = $user->select('id')->where('email', '=', $email)->find();
    $role->role_id = "1";
    $role->save();

    echo "<div id='create'>Account is created, you can enter now.</div>";
}
```

Пользователь добавляется в базу, это работает. Роль к пользователю добавляется сразу тоже.

Авторизация:

```
 public function action_login()
{
    if ($_POST){
        $username = Arr::get($_POST, 'login', '');
        $password = Arr::get($_POST, 'password', '');
        $status = Auth::instance()->login($username, $password, TRUE);
        if($status){
            echo 'Ok';
        }else{
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }
```

Не знаю в чем проблема. Помогите пожалуйста.

В модуле возвращает

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined index: trane294

MODPATH\auth\classes\kohana\auth\file.php [ 50 ]
43    if (isset($this->_users[$username]) AND $this->_users[$username] === $password)
44  {
45          // Complete the login
46      return $this->complete_login($username);
47  }
48 
49      // Login failed
50      return FALSE;
51  }
52 
53  /**
54   * Forces a user to be logged in, without specifying a password.
```

Comment: Чтобы авторизоваться у пользователя должен быть роль = 2.

Роли:
админ(1,2)

пользователь(2)

Comment: '1', 'login', 'Login privileges, granted after account confirmation'
'2', 'admin', 'Administrative user, has access to everything.'

Вы уверены?

Comment: Вроде все верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$password  = $auth->hash_password($_POST['password']);
```

Не надо хэшировать пароль, если наследуете/используете встроенную модель User, т.к. там это [делается](https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.2/master/classes/model/auth/user.php#L55) за вас.

В дополнение. Используя ORM привязывать роль можно намного красивее:

```
$user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')))
```

Comment: С паролем все верно проверил, в модуле возвращает "ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined index: trane294" 

"MODPATH\auth\classes\kohana\auth\file.php [ 50 ]
45    // Complete the login
46    return $this->complete_login($username);
47   }
48 
49   // Login failed
50   return $this->_users[$username];
51  }
52 
53  /**
54   * Forces a user to be logged in, without specifying a password."

Comment: ``auth\file.php``?  
``driver`` в ``modules/auth/config/auth.php`` какой указан?

Comment: 'driver'       => 'file',

Comment: ну вот, а должен же быть orm, не так ли?

Comment: Большое спасибо все работает!